# Updating one table with a value from another table in pecee-pixie

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the [pecee-pixie](https://github.com/skipperbent/pecee-pixie#update) library.

I am trying to update a column from one table based on values from another table however when i ran my query i simply updated the values with a text `table2.values` rather with the actual values.

This is my query:

```
$table1 = $query_builder->table('table1');
$table1
       ->leftJoin("table2", "table1.id", "=", "table2.join_id")
       ->whereNotNull("table2.values") 
       ->update(['table1.values' => 'table2.values']);
```

I would mind using [raw queries](https://github.com/skipperbent/pecee-pixie#raw-query) but i'd prefer if i didnt have to write the whole query raw. Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: oh and i did try to use backticks on table names and values but it changes nothing

Comment: leftjoin and wherenotnull isn't that a inner join?

Comment: @bassxzero Inner Join has nothing to do with null values but the rows you are selecting. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm

Comment: Although it would be faster to have a second ON criteria here rather than a where statement.